# How To refresh view controller in swift 2 every 10 minutes?

Tags: uiviewcontroller

I have an app that supposed to refresh and fetch data every 5 or 10 minutes is there any way to reload view controller in swift automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "automatically", but you can certainly have your timer routine notify a view controller that there's new data for it to show.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, what i mean is i want the viewcontroller to refresh its data every certain period of time, lets say every 10 minutes  without user interaction, is that possible ? may i have an example ?

Comment: Two questions: What does your code currently look like when the timer fires?  Where do you keep the view controller's data?

Comment: the app fetch the json data online from forecast.co, and currently i have no timer, i need to write a timer code to fetch the data from json repository